# How to bypass SSL pinning of Android Apps?

Tags: python, android, ssl, ssl-certificate, ca

I want to bypass the SSL pinning of Android apps. I was able to Bypass SSL pinning using an app "NetCapture" but now I want to do it in Python or any other way in which there is no dependency on any Android app. Can I do this by creating a self-signed CA certificate?

Comment: The point of (proper) SSL pinning is that the app expects a specific certificate. Therefore it is impossible to simply use a different certificate - no matter if self-signed or not. Note that if it worked with NetCapture then it did not use SSL pinning - it just used SSL without pinning. Without pinning you can use things like mitmproxy (written in Python).

Comment: Then what can be the possible way of bypassing SSL Pinning?

Comment: There are many and easy to find information available about the different ways - https://www.google.com/search?q=bypass+ssl+pinning+android

Comment: Yes but almost all of them work for emulators